# Installing numpy Lion with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, numpy, osx-lion

I am working on a OS X 10.7 with Python 2.7 from python.org and XCode 4.2.

1. Following these [instructions](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X#head-9ec15aabd402675e5139a8c9c727e6a23513d56a), I tried changing the `CC`, `CXX`,
   and `FFLAGS` variables and install with `sudo pip install numpy`.
   However, the installation still looks for `gcc-4.2`.
2. I tried
   installing `gcc-4.2` through MacPorts but get that `Error: gcc42
   does not build on Snow Leopard or later.`
3. When I install numpy from the precompiled binary on sourceforge, I get the following error:

   > > > import numpy

   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "", line 1, in

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py", line 137, in

   ```
   import add_newdocs
   ```

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in

   ```
   from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
   ```

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py", line 4, in

   ```
   from type_check import *
   ```

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in

   ```
   import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
   ```

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 5, in

   ```
   import multiarray
   ```

   ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

Any help?

Comment: Note that on Lion Apple's python 2.7 includes numpy

Comment: I did not know... but not scipy and matplotlib...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I recall correctly the precompiled binary on source forge is 32-bit.  It took me ages to get Numpy, Scipy, and Matplotlib set up on my macbook, it's definitely much harder than it should be.

I believe that your best option is [the Scipy superpack](http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/).  Before using the superpack you need to update to Xcode 4.3.2

So I just installed python 2.7.2 from python.org, grabbed the superpack, and now have numpy working on my machine.  After installing python 2.7.2, I did `sudo pip uninstall numpy`, which didn't remove enough.  So I cd'd into `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and moved both the numpy directory and the numpy egg to "old" versions of themselves.  Then I ran `sh install_superpack.sh` and answered *no* to the "are you installing from a repository cloned to this machine(pretty important lol, hit yes without thinking the first time).

However, now I'm able to do this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> import matplotlib
```

With no problems :)

Comment: Ah, that's the problem, possibly. I checked out Enthought's free installer but it was also 32-bit for Mac as well. Superpack looks pretty good -- do you know if this is compatible with python.org's Python 2.7 or only Apple's?

Comment: @crippledlambda I'm pretty sure that the numpy binaries should work for you.  I'm also not sure that there's another 64 bit binary out there for you to use, so to my knowledge it is your best option.  I am trying it out now though.

Comment: @crippledlambda I just installed numpy for python 2.7.2.  There were just a few bumps, editing my process into my post now.

Comment: @Nolan, wow! Thanks for the details. Worked for me too! Except `import pandas` gives error because missing `dateutil`, which is not available through `pip`. Odd. I'll have to figure this out, but indeed this is the best solution for Numpy + Scipy it seems (after deleting the old installation of Numpy). Very nice!

Comment: @Nolan, it actually required installation of `sudo pip install dateutils` though the error was that it couldn't find `dateutil`. But in any case, many thanks!

Comment: @crippledlambda glad to hear it works!  I remember wasting hours on it, so I figured a few more minutes for some precise instructions would be worth it :)

Comment: @Nolan, yes -- installation of Numpy and Scipy has always given me headaches, which makes me want to stick to R every time... (still do for some things). Hope others find this thread and your step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 4):

SuperPack worked for me (thanks, @Nolen) on OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) w/ XCode 4.5.1 installed.

Numpy worked for me using `pip install numpy` after step #1 below. But scipy would *not* install using pip. SuperPack fixed this.

The only thing I did differently was to use HomeBrew to install Python as step #1, rather than download it manually.

1. Install Python (separate from version that comes with OS X 10.8)

   - `brew install python --framework --universal`
   - `pushd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`
   - `sudo rm Current`
   - `sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current`
   - `popd`
2. Install SuperPack:

   - `curl -o install_superpack.sh https://raw.github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack/master/install_superpack.sh`
   - `sh install_superpack.sh`
   - (type your admin password several times during the installation...)